# Read CSV first line using CsvBeanReader

Tags: csv

I have a CSV file which has 3 columns and file does not have any header column but it has fixed pattern (like for first column, It will have url, Second and third column will have checksum). To process individual column values, I am using `CSVBeanReader`.
`CSVBeanReader` reads values from 2nd line with below code:

```
ICsvBeanReader beanReader = new CsvBeanReader(new FileReader(path),
                    CsvPreference.EXCEL_NORTH_EUROPE_PREFERENCE);

String[] header = beanReader.getHeader(true);
header = new String[] { "docURL", "shaCheckSum", null };

CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[3];

processors = getChecksumProcessors();

ValueObj docRecord;

while ((docRecord = beanReader.read(ValueObj.class, header, processors)) != null) {
    docRecordList.add(docRecord);
}   


private static CellProcessor[] getChecksumProcessors() {
        return new CellProcessor[] { new NotNull(), new NotNull(), null };
}
```

How should I read first line of csv file using CSVBeanReader which contains data?

CSV file contains data from first line like below:

ftp://folder_struc/filename.pdf;checksum1;checksum2

Please let me know.

Comment: I guess you should omit the String[] header = beanReader.getHeader(true); line. Try just var header = new String[] {...}

Comment: Thanks Alex ...your solution worked :) .I tried with getHeader(true) and getHeader(false) with no success . Never tried removing it. Thanks a lot .

Comment: @Alex .. I am not able to mark your response as solution..

Comment: Ok, reposted it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should omit the `String[] header = beanReader.getHeader(true);` line. Try just `var header = new String[] {...}`